# Why am i getting incorrect count of another table records while using Group by and Left Join

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my Schema for tables :

```
CREATE TABLE users  (`id` int, `name` varchar(50));
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Test 1'), (2, 'Test 2'), (3, 'Test 3');

CREATE TABLE recipes (`id` int, `user_id` int , `name` varchar(100));
INSERT INTO recipes (`id`, `user_id`, `name`) VALUES 
(null, 1, 'Receipe 1');
```

I need individual user receipe count, for that i've joined my user table with receipes, please look at below query

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, count('recipes.id') as recipes_cnt FROM `users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `recipes` AS `Recipe` ON (`User`.`id` = `Recipe`.`user_id`) 
GROUP BY `User`.`id`
```

But it's giving ***count as 1*** even if there are no receipes for user (normally it **should be zero**).

Here is mysql [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d386f/1)

Why am i getting results like this ?

please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: because you count all id with `count('recipes.id')`

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron How can i make it zero, is there any condition need to set extra ?

Comment: `count(recipes.user_id) as recipes_cnt`

Comment: because you group by `User`.`id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your SQL. replace count('recipes.id') to count(`Recipe`.id). These result gives ZERO's.

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, count(`Recipe`.id) as recipes_cnt FROM `users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `recipes` AS `Recipe` ON (`User`.`id` = `Recipe`.`user_id`) 
GROUP BY `User`.`id`
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight typo in your count:

```
count('recipes.id')
```

This is counting the *string* `"recipes.id"`.

You need to count by the actual column:

```
count(Recipe.id)
```